# How to upload JSON to server?

Tags: json, swift

I have a .json file stored in a folder on the Simulator and I'm using:

```
let jsonData = JSONDecoder().decode(Test.self, from: data)
```

to decode this file (Test is a Decodable struct). I want to upload this data to a server. But when I am using this:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: data)
```

the data that I have is not type `Data` but `Test`. Any thoughts on how to send the file?

Comment: I think you should try with `let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: jsonData)`. May be this contains data which are required to upload.

Comment: I've tried that and I'm getting this error "Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController.Test' to expected argument type 'Data?' ". Apparently, the uploadTask only works with type Data.

Comment: What is it you want? To send a file? or just the contents of the file?

Comment: `data` is the `Data` you need to upload. Passing `data` to `uploadTask` is the correct code.

Comment: Do _not_ decode the file. Just upload it, as is. It (your `data`) _is_ the JSON data already.

Answer (score 1):

```
let json = "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)
```

or from file you could do something like:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "foo.json", withExtension: "json") {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
}
```